# How to enable Bulk API v2.0

Tags: soap-api, bulk-api, bulk

We are loading data into Salesforce from Informatica and have enabled Bulk API option. But in the Salesforce Batch status pages, we see that v1 of the Bulk API is being used.

We are using 41.0 version of the API. As per documentation available, Bulk API v2 is available with 41 and above. So is there any specific settings to ensure that Bulk API v2 gets used?

Answer (score 3):

Bulk API 2.0 does not support any other contentType except for CSV.

Source:

> The format of the data being processed. Only CSV is supported.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/get_all_jobs.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/create_job.htm?search_text=json